# Create clickable links of local files using exec() command?

Tags: php

I am a beginner to PHP so please forgive any ignorance...

I am using the exec() command as following to get the list of files in my media directory..

```
<?php // exec.php
$cmd = "dir";   // Windows
exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd), $output, $status);
if ($status) echo "Exec command failed";
else
{
echo "<pre>";
foreach($output as $line) echo "<a href='$line'>$line</a> \n";
}
?>
```

The problem is it gives the list of files along with the various timestamps of the filenames-

```
 Volume in drive F is Movies 
 Volume Serial Number is 172B-1DE0 
 06/17/2011  01:11 AM             6,318 bck.gif
```

Hence, here it creates clickable link to each line for the output which needless to say does not work.

What I want is that it will only create clickable links for the filenames and not the extra meta information, which the user can then click to launch his native program like this-

```
video1.mpg
video2.mpg
bck.gif
```

Comment: why use exec? use php's functions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `exec();` to list files in the directory, PHP has many build in functions for dealing with the file system:

From the [`readdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) manual page:

```
<?php
if ($dirHandle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($nodeHandle = readdir($dirHandle ))) {
        if ($nodeHandle == '.' || $nodeHandle == '..') {
            continue;
        }
        echo "$nodeHandle \n";
    }
    closedir($dirHandle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're far better off using PHP's directory manipulation functions instead.  The scandir() function should be of particular interest to you.

- http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.dir.php
- http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Don't forget that the scandir listing will include . and .. ao you'll need to remove them from the results set unless you plan to use them for navigation.

Comment: also how do i specify to scandir the current directory without giving an explicit path??

Comment: You can remove the '.' and '..' paths by either ignoring them in your list building loop or by filtering them out with PHP's array processing features.  You can use the . path as the scandir path argument.  scandir ('.');